# When extending Array in Javascript, why does this.length mismatch with this' content?

Tags: javascript

Say I want to extend Array with a to_html() method:

```
Array.prototype.to_html = function() {
  console.log(this.length);

  for(var i in this) {
    console.log(this[i]);
  }
};
```

And I have an array:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
```

When calling `arr.to_html()`, the first line in console looks fine:

```
3
```

So far so good. But here are the following lines:

```
1
2
3
function() {
  console.log(this.length);

  for(var i in this) {
    console.log(this[i]);
  }
}
```

Oops, where does the fourth element come from? How can I get rid of it?

Comment: I'm assuming the fourth element you see is '3'? That's the 'length' property which is also part of the array object: `{1:1,2:2,3:3,length:3}`

Comment: @slebetman No. The 4th key is `to_html`, value is the function body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead to ensure you only iterate over the array items

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    console.log(this[i]);
  }
```

`for in` will iterate all properties on the object. It is including the property/method you defined on the prototype as well

Answer (score 1):

Javascript for-in loops get all the properties of an object.  But `Array`s have properties that don't come from the numerical indexes.  Try printing `i` along with `this[i]`.  You'll see at least one string-named property.

Answer (score 0):

For most of the time, it is more desirable to use `hasOwnProperty` to avoid looking up the prototype chain. The following code should get you the expected results.

```
for (var i in this) {
    if (this.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        console.log(this[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: While true here, in the general case this would still pick up non-prototype attributes set on the array that are not numeric keys.

Comment: Agreed, `this` is an array, not an object, so a numeric `for` loop should be used instead of the `for`...`in` loop.

Comment: I am not recommend the use of `for in` in this case. I am merely trying to point out that when using `for in` it is better to avoid looking up prototype chain to get a more sensible/predictable result.